# is there any way to hide/remove the progress bar in YouTube player?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am trying to hide/remove progress bar so that user can not move fast forward a video but I want other controls like play, pause, volume etc.

I know using below code in youtube api to remove controls, but it removes all controls like play, pause, volume etc. I want only to remove/hide progress bar.

playerVars: {controls: 0},

Comment: If you only can remove all buttons just use custom play... buttons?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't. Best you can do is have your viewers use third party extensions.